# How to IP of remote iOS device through its ID using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I basically work on video streaming that has to be sent on some specific iOS device using objective-c. So I want to get network IP of remote iOS device i.e iPhone, iPad or iPod using their phone IDs. I performed many searched over hear but I could not find any proper answer... I just Got code for getting IP Address of current device not of remote device.
The Objective-c code I have found for IP of current device is:

```
+ (id)sharedServices {
    static SystemServices *sharedSystemServices = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedSystemServices = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedSystemServices;
}

- (NSString *)currentIPAddress {
    return [SSNetworkInfo currentIPAddress];
}
```

Please help me to get IP address of remote device through its device ID or IMEI.

Comment: You can't really. If you have an active IP connection to the remote device then you can see what IP address you are sending data to, but that may not be the devices actual address as it may be behind network address translation, a proxy or a firewall. The normal approach is for the remote device to open the connection to the server and start receiving data. This could be in response to the server sending information via an already open connection or a push notification.  There is certainly no relation between IMEI, UUID and network address (and you can't get a devices IMEI or UUID anyway)

Comment: As Paul says, you can't do what you're asking for. A phone's IP address is both not knowable in advance, and subject to change. Paul, you should post your response as an answer. ("You can't" is a valid answer.)